# How to put converted string to datagridview image column?

Tags: c#, datagridview, base64

in database i have a column `id` and a column `pic` of table `gambar`. Column `pic` is a column of string that are converted of images, i want to put the `id` and `pic`in a datagridview, but the `pic` containing string, so i have to convert it first using base64, but i dont know how to display it to datagridview

code :

```
 using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["konekKuy"].ConnectionString))
        {
            mysqlCon.Open();
            string insertQuery = "SELECT * FROM gambar";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, mysqlCon);
            MySqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dtblLaris = new DataTable();
            sqlDa.Fill(dtblLaris);
            if (dtblLaris.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dtblLaris;
                dataGridView1.Columns["id"].HeaderText = "ID";
                dataGridView1.Columns["pic"].HeaderText = "PHOTO";

                byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(dataGridView1.Columns[1].ToString());
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
                {
                    Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
                }

                DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
                imageColumn = (DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[1];
                imageColumn.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
            }
            sqlDa.Dispose();
            mysqlCon.Close();
        }
```

do you know any better ways to display it on datagridview?

Comment: Better as in it doesn't work (well.. other than the logic flaws where it only converts one image),  or better as in it works but you think it is not optimal?

Comment: I suspect what you'll need to do is: fill your datatable using your adapter, then add a column of type Image, then iterate over it using a loop and convert all the b64 values to Image, then bind your grid by setting the DataSource

Answer (score 1):

I think the code as it is should work fine... but it is pretty unstructured and hard to read / understand

First of all it is always good practise to seperate your code into dedicated methods. This is a common principle in software engineering called [`Single Responsibility Principle`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)

If we apply the principle to your code it would look something like this:

```
private void Load()
{
    // 1) Execute Sql query
    DataTable originDataTable = QueryData("konekKuy", "SELECT * FROM gambar");

    // 2) If query returns results
    if (originDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        // 3) Convert queried DataTable to DataTable with Image 
        DataTable convertedDataTable = ConvertDataTable(originDataTable);

        // 4) Set the converted DataTable as DataGridView DataSource
        LoadDataIntoDataGrid(convertedDataTable);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No data to display!");
    }
}

public DataTable QueryData(string connectionString, string queryCommand)
{
     DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

     using (var sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionString].ConnectionString))
     {
         MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(queryCommand, sqlConnection);
         MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);

         sqlConnection.Open();

         adapter.Fill(dataTable);

         adapter.Dispose();
         sqlConnection.Close();
     }

     return dataTable;
}

public DataTable ConvertDataTable(DataTable originDataTable)
{
    // Create the new DataTable with their uppercase titles and their new types.
    var convertedDataTable = new DataTable();
    convertedDataTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
    convertedDataTable.Columns.Add("PHOTO", typeof(Image));

    // Loop through original DataTable rows and convert base64 string to Image with 'ConvertBase64ToImage' method
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in originDataTable.Rows)
    {
        var id = dataRow.Field<string>("id");
        var image = ConvertBase64ToImage(dataRow.Field<string>("pic"));

        convertedDataTable.Rows.Add(id, image);
    }

    return convertedDataTable;
}

public Image ConvertBase64ToImage(string base64)
{
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

    using (var memory = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))
    {
        return Image.FromStream(memory, true);
    }
}

public void LoadDataIntoDataGrid(DataTable convertedDataTable)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = convertedDataTable;
}
```

- The `QueryData` would contain all code which is responsible to get your data from the database. After the SQL query has been executed the `QueryData` method return the `DataTable` which contains the data from your database
- `ConvertDataTable` method takes the `DataTable` from the database query and creates a new `DataTable` which holds the same data like the original `DataTable` except the Base64 string will be converted to a `Image`
- `ConvertBase64ToImage` contains the code that converts the base64 string to a `Image` file and returns the `Image`
- The `LoadDataIntoDataGrid` method accepts a `DataTable` as parameters and handels the insertion of the data into the UIs `DataGridView`

Creating dedicated methods for each action / responsibility makes your code much easier to understand and maintain. It also makes your code testable through UnitTests which is a big deal!

I hope this helped you clean up your code